# How would I convert this form into codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter

I have the form below for a login page

```
<form action = "http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']; ?>/user/login" method = "post">
    <fieldset>
        <label for="email" class="block clearfix">
            Email Address:
            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id = "email"/> <i class="icon-user"></i>
            </span>
        </label>
        <label for ="password" class="block clearfix">
            Password:
            <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
                <input type="password" name="password" id = "password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/> <i class="icon-lock"></i>
            </span>
        </label>
        <div class="clearfix">
            <button type="submit" class="button width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
                <i class="icon-key"></i>
                Login
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I'd like to convert this to use the [form_helper](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/helpers/form_helper.html) packaged with CodeIgniter. My issue though is the documentation only showed the most basic of examples. I'm not sure how I would put so much extra data inside each `label` (including the `form_input`). What is the easiest way to convert this?

Comment: You can’t “convert” a form into a framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attributes can be provided as an array for `form_input()` calls.

If I were to recreate your `email` text box:

`<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id = "email"/>`

I would create it as:

```
$data = array(

'name' => 'email' , 
'id'   => 'email' ,
'class' => 'form_control' ,
'placeholder' => 'Email'

);

echo form_input($data);
```

Comment: The part that was confusing for be is the fact that your `form_input($data)` is (somehow) inside a `form_label();`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $attributes = array('id' => 'addsensorform'); ?>
<?php echo form_open_multipart('http://<?php echo $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];', $attributes); ?>
<fieldset>
    <label for="email" class="block clearfix">
        Email Address:
        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" name="email" id = "email"/> <i class="icon-user"></i>
        </span>
    </label>
    <label for ="password" class="block clearfix">
        Password:
        <span class="block input-icon input-icon-right">
            <input type="password" name="password" id = "password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password"/> <i class="icon-lock"></i>
        </span>
    </label>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <button type="submit" class="button width-35 pull-right btn btn-sm btn-primary">
            <i class="icon-key"></i>
            Login
        </button>
    </div>
</fieldset> 
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```